# Android: TimeOut on WebViewClient

Tags: android, webview, timer, timeout, timertask

I am trying to implement a TimeOut error handling on a webview. But unfortunately I am doing something wrong, which is causing me huge headaches. Currently I am using a `TimerTask`. To check the progress of a webpage for 10 seconds. The idea is if the page takes more than 10 seconds to load, the app should display a custom "no I-net" view.

Here is my code so far:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

            if (mNoInternetConnectionView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                mNoInternetConnectionView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            mTimer = new Timer();

            TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (webView.getProgress() < 100) {
                                handleInternetProblems();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            };

            mTimer.schedule(timerTask, 10000, 1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {               
            cancelTimer();

            if (!internetError && webView.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
                webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            return mCheckoutUrlHandler.handleUrl(webView, url);
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, final SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {

            //handle ssl error
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
            handleInternetProblems();
        }
    });
```

And here are my `handleInternetProblems()` and my `cancelTimer()`:

```
 private void handleInternetProblems() {
    internetError = true;
    webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mNoInternetConnectionView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mKLLoadingAnimation.hide();
    cancelTimer();
}

private void cancelTimer() {

    if (mTimer != null) {
        mTimer.cancel();
        mTimer.purge();
        mTimer = null;
    }
}
```

The problem is that if I click on an URL on the webview and I try to load another webpage I get `mNoInternetConnectionView` and I can see that `handleInternetProblems()` is called multiple times inside `TimerTask`. What am I doing wrong? How can I prevent this from happening?